# Euler's Formula transformation given $\Re \lbrace (x -j)e^{j\theta} \rbrace$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

I'm trying to understand a derivation in a paper:

$$\begin{align}
 F_X(x)  &= P \lbrace X \leq x \rbrace  \\
      &= P\left\lbrace \frac{\sin \theta}{1 - \cos \theta} \leq x \right\rbrace  \\
      &= P \left\lbrace \sin \theta + x \cos \theta \leq x \right\rbrace  \\
      &= P \left\lbrace \Re \lbrace (x -j)e^{j\theta} \right\rbrace \leq x \rbrace  \\
      &= P \left\lbrace \sqrt{1+x^2}\cos(\theta - \cos^{-1}\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}) \leq x \right\rbrace  \\
      &= P \left\lbrace \cos(\theta - \cos^{-1}\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}) \leq \frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} \right\rbrace  \\
      &= P \left\lbrace 2\cos^{-1}\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} \leq \theta \leq x \right\rbrace  \\
      &= \int^{2\pi}_{2\cos^{-1}\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}}\frac{1}{2\pi}d\theta  \\
      &= 1- \frac{1}{\pi}\cos^{-1}\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}
\end{align}
$$

My problem is the transformation from $$P \left\lbrace \Re \lbrace (x -j)e^{j\theta}  \leq x\right\rbrace$$ to $$P \left\lbrace \sqrt{1+x^2}\cos(\theta - \cos^{-1}\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}) \leq x \right\rbrace.$$

All I get when transforming is $P\left\lbrace \sin \theta + x \cos \theta \leq x \right\rbrace$.

Thank you.